# Put divs on the same line

Tags: css, html

I have a form where I want to put some `<div>` elements on the same line.

I want to have confirm password in the same line as password.

**HTML**

```
<form action="pages/php/signup.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <div>Name :
            <div id="gtext_form">
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="st_column">E-mail :
            <div class="text_form">
                <input type="text" name="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nd_column">Login :
            <div class="text_form">
                <input type="text" name="login" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="st column">Password :
            <div class="text_form">
                <input type="password" name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nd_column">Confirm password :
            <div class="text_form">
                <input type="password" name="password2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <input type="submit" name="valider" value="  OK   " />
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#gtext_form input {
    width: 640px;
    height: 20px;
}
.text_form input {
    width: 280px;
}
.st_column {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    display: inline;
}
.nd_column {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
    display: inline;
}
.line {
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/toulmek/7a9dL/)

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline` on the `<div>` elements?

Comment: yes, I tried many things display:inline was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: You have it placed in a separate div. Copy what you did for the Email and Login.

Comment: Using float and inline at the same time makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem it's exactely the same thing with Email and Login !

Comment: Was going to ask if that was the @Overv from Gmod, clicked on profile. Confirmed. Hi there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is en error in your class name:

```
    <div class="st column">Password :<div class="text_form"><input type="password" name="password"/></div></div>
```

The name should be **st_column**

Comment: Thank you, I lost almost 2 hours for this stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

Hi you didn't have the class for the password correct int he html. It was missing and underscore. Trying something like this:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7a9dL/3/)

Change your class for Password in your html to: `class="st_column"`

CSS

```
#gtext_form input {
    width: 640px;
    height: 20px;
}
.text_form input {
    width: 280px;
}
.st_column {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    display: inline;
}
.nd_column {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
    display: inline;
}
.line {
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second `<div class="line">`

You have a div that reads:

```
<div class="st columns">
```

However this should be:

```
<div class="st_columns">
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7a9dL/5/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason the confirm password wasn't on the same line as the password is because you are missing the _ in the classname: http://jsfiddle.net/7a9dL/2/

Corrected HTML:

```
<form action="pages/php/signup.php" method="post"> 
<div><div>Name :<div id="gtext_form"><input type="text" name="name"/></div></div></div>
<div class="line">
    <div class="st_column">E-mail :<div class="text_form"><input type="text" name="email"/></div></div>
    <div class="nd_column">Login :<div class="text_form"><input type="text" name="login"/></div></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
    <div class="st_column">Password :<div class="text_form"><input type="password" name="password"/></div></div>
    <div class="nd_column">Confirm password :<div class="text_form"><input type="password" name="password2"/></div></div>
</div>
<div class="line"><input type="submit" name="valider" value="  OK   " /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this :

```
.line div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Tested with Firefox 27.